# Activate pdf library in php - Windows (32 bit)

Tags: php, windows, pdf

I have an Apache server running PHP-5.3.0 for Windows. For the creation of pdf files, I need to activate the pre-bundled pdf library (referred [here](http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/generate-pdfs-php)) in my php by editing the configuration file. How can I do this?

Or is there any other way to enable pdf creation?

Comment: A PDF library in Apache? That would be news to me. What library are you referring to? Do you mean a PHP extension?

Comment: sorry.. not apache, I mean php.. `:P`

Comment: @blasteralfred locate php.ini and see what extensions are commented out by a `;`. Remove the `;` from whichever extension you want to activate

Comment: @blasteralfred please update the topic when you search for a PHP solution...

Comment: not working :( ... no pdf in ini file..

Comment: You may need to install it manually. The vendor should have instructions for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using `TCPDF`.. Its easy to handle. No need to edit php.ini.

Answer (score 0):

Go to PHP's root directory > php.ini. Ctrl+F 'extension=php_pdflib.dll' and remove the semicolon (;) at the start of the line. Then restart Apache. If the semicolon isn't there, then it should already be activated. If there isn't any results from the Ctrl+F, it likely means you don't have it installed. You could try adding 'extension=php_pdflib.dll' (anywhere will do).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a small file to test whether the library is loaded, just write in it:

```
<?php phpinfo();
```

Watch for `php.ini` in the output of this script, and add the following line to the file (you may need additional privileges to do that, right click your editor -> `Run as Administrator`):

```
extension=php_pdflib.dll
```

Restart apache, and check that pdf has been installed by checking the aforementioned phpinfo file.

Unless you're doing really advanced PDF stuff (and you need the non-free version of php-pdf for that), I can really recommend [Prince XML](http://princexml.com/). It converts XML and HTML into PDF and adds additional CSS properties, like page dimensions and numbers, PDF bookmarks and the like. Their [documentation](http://princexml.com/doc/7.0/) is better in demonstrating that than any of their marketing pages.